# Share auth between django and react

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

I have a website with the default django authentication system. The whole website is static and I would like to have a couple pages dynamic using React app as frontend.

I expect these dynamic pages to make a some http requests to the django server. My understanding is that I can use axios on the frontend and deal with the requests on the backend with Django Rest Framework.

I think the current authentication system works fine, how can I make  axios requests to DRF using the existing user's session ?

Answer (score 1):

Once the user logs in, get the token from the backend using the following:

```
axios.post(`http://localhost:${port_number}/${urlpattern}`, {
     headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    data: {
      username,
      password
})
   .then(response => {
      console.log(`token: ${response.token}`);
   })
```

Port number could be 8000 and url pattern could be /api/auth/login for example.
This answer mostly comes from the last reference.

References

Youtube.  Full Stack React & Django [1] - Basic REST API.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uyei2iDA4Hs.  (Accessed 23 April, 2021).

Youtube. Full Stack React & Django [2] - Implementing React.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GieYIzvdt2U.  (Accessed 23 April, 2021).

Youtube.  Full Stack React & Django [3] - Redux & HTTP.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmL8iaLMnQ0.  (Accessed 23 April, 2021).

Youtube. Full Stack React & Django [4] - Error Handling & Alerts.  https://www.youtube.a/watch?v=Fia-GGgHpK0.  (Accessed 23 April, 2021).

Youtube. Full Stack React & Django [5] - Django Token Authentication.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0d7cIfiydAc.  (Accessed 23 April, 2021).

Youtube.  Full Stack React & Django [6] - Auth State & Private Routes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmAc4wQikwY. (Accessed 23 April, 2021).

Comment: Thank you but these methods implement a token, for example with knox or jwt, and make it the obly way to authenticate the user. In my case, user is already authenticated by the django system (no additional token) when loading the page. I want to make sure that from this original authentication, I can still make ajax requests,with axios for example.

Comment: @AlixL  I see what you mean.  I haven't been able to find anything on it.  This link: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLRM7ROnmA9FxCtnLoIHAs6hIkJyd1dEx might help, but the information is outdated.

Comment: @AlixL  The first video in the playlist has a pinned comment from the uploader indicating that they have a paid, updated version (course) of the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you already build your urls.py file and have the endpoints working fine, you can start the django server using your ip address/port and in axios just replace the url. like this.

```
  axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: `http://${IP_ADRESS}:8000/api/auth/login`,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  data: {
    username,
    password,
  },
})
```

dont forget to set your IP adress in ALLOWED_HOST in settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['IP_ADDRESS']
```

Comment: But such request would force me to have 2 login functions. I already have a login page accessible here : ip:8000\login. I would like to use this authentication to let my user request data from axios.

Comment: So just use your path. All I wrote was an example, you can add different data in the request, different path as long as it works.

Comment: But I do not want the user to sign in again. I want him to access data. From a axios request, how can I access "request.user"?

Comment: You dont need to sign in again if you send a token when the user logs in for first time, you can store this token on your local storage, then when you make calls to your api you send the data with your token, django will know wich user is making the request because of the token

Comment: How can I pass the token with Django? How do I access this token from React?

Comment: for example im using knox auth and in my case after successfully login I send the token in a response like this                                                                                                                       def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #your login user api
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user,
                                      context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1],
        })

Comment: Tahnks, but this is using DRF aurh system. How can I do the same with plain django auth system?

Comment: @AlixL Use the token from the axios response object.